# Правка чужих ответов

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка, правки

Иногда кто-то правит мои ответы. Но мне в лом проверять даже опечатку в одну букву, а тем более когда весь экран красный от правок. Я просто удаляю правленые ответы, дабы не приписывали мне того, чего я не говорил. Хуже стал ответ, лучше - не важно. Это уже не моё. Иногда ответы мои бывают полезными и даже отмечаются зелёной "птичкой". Так что если не хотите лишать свою базу, людей правильных ответов, то лучше напишите свой, а мой удалите. Когда я удаляю взамен ведь ничего не остаётся. Правильно?

Comment: Отдельно прокомментирую правки этого вопроса: Николас убрал пару слов, которые не соответствуют нормам общения на сайте, а я поставил верные метки, отражающие содержание вопроса.

Answer (score 9):

Насколько я понимаю, речь вот об этом ответе: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/480347/181472

Постараюсь объяснить вам, что происходит и почему это нормально.

Идея StackOverflow в том, чтобы накапливать решения практических задач. Именно поэтому вопросы и ответы должны сохраняться после того, как решена задача конкретного автора вопроса. Вы можете редактировать свой ответ, но удалять его не нужно — он является частью общей коллекции решений.

По этой же причине приветствуется редактирование вопросов и ответов. У них будут сотни и тысячи читателей. Любая правка, которая улучшает читаемость и понятность, экономит много времени и нервных клеток разработчиков по всему миру.

#### Подробнее о редактировании

Редактировать чужие вопросы и ответы на StackOverflow можно и даже рекомендуется, но в определенных рамках:

- Можно улучшать форматирование. Например, в вашем ответе редактор поменял самодельный список с маркерами `1)`, `2)` на список в разметке Markdown. На обычной версии сайта это лишь немного улучшает читаемость, а вот на мобильной версии и в мобильном приложении первый вариант может показываться совсем плохо.
- Можно убирать долгие приветствия, вступительные речи и обещания награды. Но это не ваш случай.

Что в правке нельзя делать:

- Правка не должна менять смысл ответа. Как раз ваше требование: «не приписывали мне того, чего я не говорил». Если где-то редактор напишет от вашего имени совсем не то, что вы имели в виду — смело откатывайте правку и отмечайте тревогой для модератора. Мы посмотрим и постараемся донести до редактора, почему так делать не стоит.
- Правка не должна исправлять (и тем более добавлять) ошибки в коде. Особенно в вопросах. (Орфографические ошибки, наоборот, можно исправлять)

В каждом вопросе и ответе доступна история правок. Там есть информация о каждом редакторе и его вкладе. Если правка вредоносная — ее можно откатить через ссылку в истории. Также к любому из редакторов можно обращаться в комментариях через `@Имя`.

#### Подробнее об удалении

Все вопросы и ответы публикуются под открытой лицензией CC-BY-SA. Грубо говоря, они являются общественным достоянием — примерно как открытое и свободное ПО. Так что публикуя их на SO вы заранее соглашаетесь с тем, что они останутся открытыми и доступными.

Представьте, что вы написали некоторую программу. А потом другой разработчик внёс в нее какие-то изменения. Если это opensource – вы же не будете удалять её с гитхаба и отзывать лицензию? А если код коммерческий и его правит коллега по работе — не будете требовать, чтобы только вы имели право поддерживать свой код?

---

Вся история IT построена на том, что мы используем наработки предшественников и объединяем свои усилия чтобы сделать то, что не под силу одному. Поэтому, пожалуйста, рассматривайте правки как часть обычного рабочего процесса. Кто-то потратил своё время на то, чтобы сделать ваш ответ более читаемым, понятным, аккуратным. Кстати, это обычно повышает количество «плюсов» на ответе. Авторство ответа всегда остаётся за вами. В редких случаях, когда правка портит вопрос, вы можете её откатить.

Кстати, об этом есть целый раздел справки: [«Почему кто-то может редактировать мои сообщения? Как работает система редактирования?»](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/editing)

Comment: Надеюсь речь об ошибках в коде, а не орфографических...

Comment: @VenZell: разумеется

Answer (score 8):

Вносить улучающие правки как в ответы, так и в вопросы необходимо. Более того, эта функциональность заложена в сайт с самого первого дня. Stack Overflow – это пересечения коллективного блога, совместно редактируемой вики и форума. Все мы помним эту схему:

[image: диаграмма]

Для механизма коллективной правки введены два инструменты:

- Предлагаемые правки анонимными пользователями.
- Правка сообщений участниками с необходимой репутацией.

**Почему в ваши сообщения вносится правка?**

Потому что, с большой вероятностью, в них можно что-то улучшить! Модель Stack Overflow подразумевает постоянно обновляемую базу знаний, которая отражает текущее состояние технологий.

Поясню. К пример, в какой-то момент на iPhone нельзя было запустить флеш. Был задан вопрос и дан соответствующий ответ. Но со временем все изменилось, технологии обновились. Необходимо либо удалить неверный ответ, либо внести улучшающую правку. Хоть это и более радикальный пример, но в нем можно увидеть, что если запретить правку, все идея постоянно обновляемой базы знаний сойдет на нет.

**Зачем вообще вносить правку?**

Вопрос задается один раз, ответ публикуется один раз. Страницу вопроса и ответа читают сотни тысяч раз за время её существования. Улучшив вопрос или ответ пусть даже незначительным изменением, который приведет, к примеру, к ускорению прочтения темы на 3 секунды, мы можем получить в результате сотни сэкономленных часов! И это реальные человеческие жизни!

Вспомните, сколько времени занимает у вас прочтение вопроса или ответа на любом из сайтов Stack Overflow? Вот по этому и надо вносить правки.

**Они перестают быть вашими?**

Это не так. Вы автор сообщения. После правки, добавляется автор правки. Все изменения можно легко отследить. Более того, лицензия размещения содержимого на сайте подразумевает, что вы согласны с тем, что все, что вы опубликуете может быть изменено или использовано повторно в личных целях любым участником сообщества.

*Помните, вопрос задается не для отвечающего, ответ публикуется не для задающего, вопрос задается и отвечается для сотен и тысяч наших коллег, которые столкнутся с подобной проблемой в будущем и попадут на сайт из поисковика!*

Answer (score 5):

Я считаю, что вы правы лишь отчасти.

И ответы, и вопросы должны правиться только с целью улучшения их качества.
Если кто-то исказил смысл вашего ответа своей правкой, вы можете откатить ее.
Чтобы подобное не повторялось вновь, вы можете попытаться связаться с автором правки в этом [**чате**](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462/stack-overflow--). Как вариант, если правка носит деструктивный характер, сообщите об инциденте модератору в чате или здесь же, на мете.

Далее я выскажу свое мнение относительно вашего предложения.

Если правка улучшает ваше сообщение, например, в ней исправлены орфографические ошибки, не стоит из-за нее его удалять.
Вдумайтесь, она же не искажает смысл вашего ответа, а следовательно ваши опасения по поводу присваивания вам чужих слов в этом случае напрасны.

Ваша позиция по поводу улучшенных вопросов для меня не понятна.
Сайтом пользуются тысячи людей. Наверняка многим из них удобнее читать структурированный ответ, не содержащий ошибок и опечаток. Вы с этим не согласны?

Подчеркну еще раз, ни к чему бросаться в крайности и удалять свои ответы из-за исправленных опечаток. 
Во-первых, подобные правки, если они не искажают смысл вашего ответа, не противоречат правилам сайта. Для этого предусмотрен встроенный функционал, что, как бы, намекает. Во-вторых, если ваши ответы были полезны пользователям, то они, скорее всего, будут восстановлены модераторами или привилегированными пользователями.

Угрозы лишить сайт человека, дающего правильные ответы, выглядят странно и не думаю, что они будут действенными. Мету посещают далеко не все пользователи сайта, а значит ваш посыл не дойдет до всех, кто имеет возможность правки.

Comment: В любом случае, в качестве жеста вежливости по отношению к автору текста, неплохо бы оставлять комментарий о том, что было исправлено. Тому, кто правит не задумываясь, имеет смысл ожидать и бездумного отката собственной правки.

Comment: А разве автор не видит сообщений в истории правок? Или вы об отдельном комментарии?

Comment: Ну, или в истории (но не отписка на два слова, а обращение к живому человеку), или, если в истории не помещается, отдельным комментарием.

Comment: @VladD При правке запятых предлагаете приводить список всех нарушенных правил русского языка? При правке меток — объяснять смысл и назначение каждой метки на несколько абзацев? Давайте не будем увлекаться. Эти описания в истории правок никто не читает, в том числе даже вырожденный случай в лице ТС. Откатывается ничтожный процент правок, ожидание отката при отсутсвии комментария — это какая-то несмешная фантазия. Если кто-то совершает какую-то серьёзную ошибку постоянно, если проблема распространённая, то согласен, комментарий уместен. А так — жирно будет.

Comment: @Discord: Ну, тогда и автор вопроса имеет право посчитать, что слишком много чести правке от непонятно кого. Как насчёт уважения и предупредительного отношения друг к другу?

Comment: @Discord: Ну и давайте не доводить до абсурда: список правил нужен лишь если автор оспаривает грамматические правки. А так — просто «улучшил орфографию». Да и то, я бы не правил всё, что в принципе может быть авторским стилем. Автор имеет право писать жи-/ши- через Ы, если он так считает правильным.

Comment: @VladD Если хотите тратить время на комментарии, которые никто не читает, которые практически не влияют на откат правок — пожалуйста, я не против. Я вообще сторонник аккуратных логов. Но мне лень, и на это ничто не способно повлиять. / Что же касается авторского стиля, то плевал я на любовь к ЖЫ/ШЫ с Эйфелевой башни. И да, я буду продолжать утыкивать сообщения Баракина заглавными буквами, какое бы омерзение они у него ни вызывали. :Р

Comment: @Discord: Мне кажется, если ещё есть смысл править ошибки, то править сознательно применяемый человеком стиль нехорошо. Представьте себе, что вы выпрямили бы лесенку Маяковского или заменили неологизм Хлебникова на что-нибудь встречающееся у Даля. Или убрали Залго из ответа про html + regex.

Comment: @VladD Есть стиль, есть нарушение правил. Стихи лесенкой — стиль, выдумывание неологизмов — стиль, даже расстановка тире от балды — стиль. А вот ЖЫ/ШЫ, предложения со строчной буквы, -тся/-ться и прочее — надругательство над великими и могучим, посему подлежит исправлению. Сейчас на меня можно наброситься с воплями про постоянно изменяющийся язык, но где-то границу надо проводить всё-таки, и ЖЫ/ШЫ — далеко за любой разумной границей.

Comment: @Discord: А олбанский? Ну да, старьё и экзотический эксперимент с позиции текущего дня, но всё же достаточно занормативизированный вариант альтернативной громатеги.

Comment: @Discord: Я к тому, что лично мне, например, сложно провести грань между ошибкой и стилем, поэтому я и не пытаюсь. Поэтому я правлю в основном лишь уплывшую разметку.

Comment: @VladD Я наглый вандал, вы же меня знаете, поэтому угрызений совести от правки стиля не испытываю.