# Автор вернул чрезмерно обширный заголовок вопроса и вандализировал свой ответ к нему

Tags: обсуждение

**Обновление:** Автор исправил заголовки у рассматриваемого примера и нового вопроса (а ответ модератор откатил до содержательного). Но общий вопрос остался. Как поступать с подобными вопросами/ответами? Каждый раз обсуждение создавать? (это создаёт излишнее трение: результат, что меньше вопросов имеют информативные заголовки — потенциально больше людей напрасно по ссылкам ходят — хуже [сигнал/шум](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4181/23044))

---

[Первая версия заголовка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/revisions/739967/1):

> Работа со строками, замена символов

я её [заменил, используя цитату текста из самого вопроса, на](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/revisions/739967/6):

> Работа со строками, замена символов: заменить одинаковые подряд идущие символы на “сигнатуру”

Что более специфично. Чтобы напрасно не завлекать людей из поисковика, у которых проблема подпадает под изначальный всеохватывающий заголовок, но не имеет никакого отношения к самому вопросу автора.

Автор отвечал на уточняющие комментарии под вопросом. Возражений против правки заголовка не было высказано.

Автор опубликовал [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/revisions/740178/1), с кодом который пытается решить проблему (не знаю рабочий или нет). Затем, автор заменил ответ на (убрав код):

> C использованием `string` все решается небольшой функцией. Вопрос закрыт

(подобный "ответ" в контексте вопроса стал практически бесполезен) и вернул чрезмерно обширную [версию заголовка вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/revisions/739967/9):

> Строковые типы, замена символов

что расплывчато и не соответствует содержимому вопроса (Кодирование длин серий -- RLE).

Хотелось бы вернуть более содержательные версии заголовка вопроса, ответа.  Есть за/против доводы?

Comment: Расплывчатый вопрос и невнятный ответ совершенно бесполезны другим посетителям, а топикстартер свои какие-то вопросы однозначно уже решил. Поэтому конкретный вопрос решаем, а общее решение подобных тем упрется в вопрос: насколько топикстартеру принадлежит его  вопрос? Имху, самое безболезненное это создавать копию вопроса, а автору пусть остаётся его версия. Гугл разберётся, куда направить трафик.

Comment: @AK: "создавать копию вопроса" -- это не реалистичное решение. Это всё равно что сказать: «Автор имеет право оставить заголовок: "Помогите решить задачу" , а не нравится, свой вопрос задавай» Вы видели много копий вопросов на сайте создаётся? Я что-то не замечал. Для сравнения я сотни размытых заголовков, используя буквальные *фразы самого автора* из вопроса, делал более специфичными.

Answer (score 1):

Каждый раз создавать обсуждение вовсе нет необходимости.

Право на улучшение сообщения -- [один из важных элементов stackoverflow](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2279/213987), отражённых в [справке по редактированию](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/editing):

> Правки должны быть существенными и **улучшать** оригинальное сообщение

Правом на улучшение обладают как анонимные пользователи (после ревью), так и пользователи с определённой репутацией, так и автор исходного сообщения (возможность вносить правки в собственный текст и утверждать/отклонять предложенные правки).

Вы приводите конкретные примеры правок и для меня очевидно, что это были правки, значительно улучшающие пост.

Конкретизация заголовка -- это очевидное благо, которое улучшает возможности поиска. Антипример из соседнего сообщества:

[image: Однотипные заголовки в сообществе русского языка]

Видите, что можно улучшить заголовок -- улучшайте! Для этого не нужно создавать тему на мете каждый раз, просто берите и правьте.

Что по второй правке. Когда некто (пусть даже это сам автор!) правит ответ и вместо подробного ответа с кодом оставляет намёк на какую-то функцию -- это вероятнее всего правка вандальная.

Что делать участнику, если он видит вандальную правку? Правильно -- откатить. По-прежнему нет смысла по какой-то отдельной правке обращаться на мету и создавать ещё одну тему. Откатили -- забыли.

Общее направление вам понятно? Всё, что улучшает сообщение -- можно и нужно улучшать, делайте безбоязненно. По этому поводу не нужно создавать новые темы на мете.

Далее. Есть расхожая фраза о том, что свобода человека безгранична и заканчивается лишь там, где начинается свобода другого человека. 
Так вот, если ваши правки или откаты не встречают никакого сопротивления со стороны других участников сообщества (намеренно не выделяю автора -- он точно такой же участник сообщества), то можете спокойно продолжать правки, руководствуясь правилом "правка должна значительно улучшать сообщение".

А что делать, если с вашими правками не согласны?

Во-первых, вы всегда имеете возможность обсудить правки в комментариях к вопросу/ответу, зачастую это самый быстрый способ придти к консенсусу. Во-вторых, вы можете обратиться за помощью в основной чат сообщества, как правило там находятся онлайн достаточно опытные участники, которые помогут советом. В-третьих, вы можете обратиться на мету или к модератору.

В качестве примера представим ситуацию, что автор ответа посмотрел на свой код, увидел, что он громоздок, избыточен и можно заменить несколько строк кода на одну -- вызов библиотечной функции. Возможна такая ситуация? Вполне возможна, в своём конкретном случае вы говорите о том, что не знаете этого языка программирования. Сомневаетесь -- лучше оставьте как есть или спросите совета у более знающих людей, возможно тот код и не стоило спасать, но стоило конкретизировать, какую конкретно функцию стоило вызвать и привести пример, решающий исходную задачу. (Из личного субъективного: я обычно пишу Update *после* исходного текста ответа, чтобы можно было лучше видеть ход мыслей)

PS Несколько ссылок на смежные темы:

- [Правка чужих ответов](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2277/213987)
- [Изменение вопроса - подмена или дополнение?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2297/213987)
- [Приветствуется ли правка вопроса "под корень"](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3537/213987)
- [Стоит ли насильно редактировать вопрос](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2134/213987)

Comment: *«Видите, что можно улучшить заголовок -- улучшайте! Для этого не нужно создавать тему на мете каждый раз, просто берите и правьте.»* — заголовок **уже** был улучшен, но автор его вернул на чрезмерно обширный вариант (посмотрите на заголовок текущего обсуждения). Вопрос что делать, если выражаемое намерение автора противоречит интересам сайта.

Comment: @jfs По-моему я вполне чётко ответил на этот вопрос: нужно правки расценивать с точки зрения "улучшают ли пост". Если намерения кого-либо, в т.ч. и автора являются вандальными -- то их нужно пресекать. Собственно, именно вы натолкнули меня на этот ответ -- в комментариях к вопросу я сначала был готов предлагать учитывать некий приоритет автора в его вопросе (и делать дубли), однако полистав правоприменительную практику на мете увидел, что это не совсем подходящее решение. Мы [немножко](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2279/213987) вики, не стоит сильно акцентироваться на эго автора.