# Пример в чужой ответ или новый ответ с примером

Tags: обсуждение, ответы, ответ-ссылка

Например, в вопросах нашёл подходящий неплохой ответ со ссылками на документацию. Но в ответе не было никакого примера, поэтому пришлось дальше продолжить поиск и найти/написать требуемые несколько строк.

Как лучше поступить в этой ситуации - править чужой ответ и вставить небольшой пример или написать новый ответ с этим примером?

Comment: Можете привести пример такого ответа? Ответы-ссылки могут быть разными

Comment: У меня пример с английского сайта (https://stackoverflow.com/a/2439110/11619532), но я думаю принципы должны быть более менее похожи?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ответы-ссылки на вопросы могут быть разными, и это зависит не столько от самого ответа, сколько от вопроса.

1. На вопросы с просьбой посоветовать модуль / литературу для тех или иных нужд ответ-ссылка [является приемлемым](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1638/) ответом, если кроме ссылки ответ содержит название модуля / литературного издания, на которые ведёт ссылка. Иначе - см. следующий пункт
2. На вопросы, касающиеся конкретной работы того или иного кода /
   модуля / алгоритма ответы-ссылки без примеров [не
   приветствуются](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1805),
   поскольку ссылки имеют свойство "плавать". Сегодня ссылка есть, и
   она решает вопрос, а завтра её нет, и ответа, как такового, тоже
   нет.
3. Если ссылка ведёт к ответу на подобный вопрос на
   [EnSO](https://stackoverflow.com/), вы можете попросить дополнить
   ответ переводом ответа с EnSO.

В первом случае ответ является полноценным. Если в этом есть необходимость, автор вопроса может подробнее спросить о работе модуля в отдельном вопросе, или же попросить автора ответа дополнить ответ примером.

Во втором и третьем случае вы сами можете попросить дополнить ответ в комментариях, или же нажать под сообщением кнопку <kbd>Тревога</kbd>, выбрать пункт `Не является ответом`, тем самым передать ответ-ссылку на рассмотрение. Возможно, ответ будет удалён либо дополнен.

---

Субъективное мнение:
Я считаю неэтичным попытки внести правки в чужой ответ, кроме случаев, когда ответ является общим, либо случаев, когда речь идёт о мелких правках опечаток, форматирования, грамматики и пунктуации.

Однако это касается тех ответов, которые не были помечены как правильные. Если ответ помечен, как правильный, либо имеет весомый положительный рейтинг, его дополнение [может быть оправдано](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2277), если оно не нарушает изначального посыла автора ответа.

Если же вносимая вами правка каким-либо образом противоречит автору ответа, от неё стоит отказаться и опубликовать отдельный ответ.